# Origin of "It won't be done by next Tuesday"

Tags: world-war-one, england, language

This may seem ridiculous but I'll give it a shot anyway. Always very interested in history, especially figuring out where sayings came from. Been watching Downton Abbey for probably the hundredth time and there is a saying that is repeated multiple times. Anytime it's a complicated issue that will take time to work through, someone says "it won't be done by next Tuesday." It's finally broken me and I'm dying to know where this colloquialism came from.

I tried a few internet searches with various wording and nothing productive has come of that. I know the writers did a lot of research, so perhaps it is period specific, though it could be a common English saying that is modern they slipped in not thinking about it. Please someone satisfy this burning curiosity!

Comment: You might have more luck with this one on https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you show that phrase used *anywhere* else? If not it may be an inside 'running' joke only relevant to the show itself.

Comment: Actually, I'd suggest [Movies&TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/). No matter what the ultimate origin of the phrase, we DO know it came from a TV show.

Comment: "Next Tuesday" has a number of meanings, and it typically does not mean April 10 (today is April 4, a Wednesday). Some are rather vulgar. I'll second moving this question to the english SE.

Answer (score 1):

This was posted a while ago but I have the answer.
“I’m not saying it will be done by Tuesday” basically means because everything official was closed at the weekend, no work got done. Monday was a day for catching up on work from Friday and dealing with business received while closed over the weekend. Therefore Tuesday was the usual day for business replies.

Comment: Hi Mitchell and welcome to History SE. Can you provide a source for this?